# EntityFramework 6.1.3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to install Entity Framework 6.1.3 in new asp.net mvc example project.

I go into the "manage nuget packages"-menu - select Entity Framework (latest version). 
The installation process runs through.

When using my newly created DbContext-class in a controller (for example) I keep getting the following error ..

Could not load file or assembly"EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0,
   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" or one of its
   dependencies

I tried to deleted and reinstall entityframework nuget package.. 
Tried with Nuget Package Manager Console - same error.
I also tried  Version 6.1.2 - same error.

In my web.config it says the following

```
<section name="entityFramework"      
type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection,   
EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,      
PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
```

What should I have to do to make that work ?
Why does nuget keeps setting up wrong entries in web.config..

I'm using .net 4.5.2 with Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise

Comment: Try to use the Nuget command line and try to remove the installed version  by running this command `Uninstall-Package EntityFramework -Version 6.0.0` . make sure you choose the right project(s) then try to install the version you want running this command `Install-Package EntityFramework`

Comment: web config is not having the changes

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the Nuget command line to remove the installed version and it's dependencies by running this command `Uninstall-Package EntityFramework` but you will need to remove the dependent library `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework`  as well.

Make sure you have the right project(s) selected in the Nugetmanager command window and try this commands in this order:

1. `Uninstall-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework`
2. `Uninstall-Package EntityFramework`
3. `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework`

last command will install last version of `EF` as well.

Answer (score -1):

After installing it goto Nuget manager in references then update it

Comment: *Nuget manager in references* Where is that? Also, why update right after installing? NuGet won't even offer that option.This "answer" is incomprehensible and it doesn't make sense.

Comment: you can go to solution explorer -> right click on the reference and you'll find manage NuGet packages, so that solution because he said that after installing 6.1.3 but he always finds version 6.0.0 so, I suggest that solution.

Comment: Version (assembly version) is always 6.0.0.0 for EF6 versions. They clearly tell they install a specific version with NuGet (6.1.2, 6.1.3) so it doesn't make sense to update afterwards. The exception is not related to NuGet.